# Haskell foldr unexpectedly gives an error

Tags: haskell

Why does writing map using foldr this way

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map' f xs = foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc) []
```

give the following error?

```
test.hs:2:13: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[b]’ with actual type ‘t0 a -> [b]’
• Probable cause: ‘foldr’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the expression: foldr (\ x acc -> f x : acc) []
  In an equation for ‘map'’:
      map' f xs = foldr (\ x acc -> f x : acc) []
• Relevant bindings include
    xs :: [a] (bound at test.hs:2:8)
    f :: a -> b (bound at test.hs:2:6)
    map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] (bound at test.hs:2:1)
|
2 | map' f xs = foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc) []
|             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Note the GHC hint: Probable cause: ‘foldr’ is applied to too few arguments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't use `xs`. You can either write:

```
map' f xs = foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc) [] xs
```

or

```
map' f = foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc) []
```